# Apache POI reading from a file that does not exist

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache's POI to read from a .docx file, make some necessary replacements and additions and write the final file to a new location, and more specifically my Desktop. The first execution produces the correct result. However, when I perform more executions, it seems that the POI reads from what was supposed to be the output file of the previous execution, rather than reading from the input file located in the resources of my project. Below is my code:

```
OutputStream fo = null;
try {

        XWPFDocument invoiceDocument = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(getClass().getResource("/com/euthimiadis/resources/Proforma_Invoice.docx").getPath()));
        for (XWPFTable t:invoiceDocument.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : t.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell c : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph p : c.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                            String text = r.getText(0);
                            
                            if (text!=null) {
                                if (text.contains("#CURRENTDATE")) {
                                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                    String dateOnly = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
                                    text = text.replace("#CURRENTDATE", dateOnly);
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#ClientName")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#ClientName", this.invoiceClient.getFullName());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#Address")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#Address", this.invoiceClient.getClientAddress());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#TIN")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#TIN", this.invoiceClient.getClientTIN());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#ContactPerson")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#ContactPerson", this.invoiceClient.getContactPerson());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#Telephone")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#Telephone", this.invoiceClient.getTelephoneNumber());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#IBAN")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#IBAN", this.invoiceClient.getClientIBAN());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#Swift")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#Swift", this.invoiceClient.getClientSwift());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#Branch")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#Branch", this.invoiceClient.getClientBranch());
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#TVA")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#TVA", this.invoiceTVA);
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#PlaceOfLoading")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#PlaceOfLoading", this.termsOfLoading);
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#TermsOfSale")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#TermsOfSale", this.termsOfSale);
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                else if (text.contains("#TermsOfPayment")) {
                                    text = text.replace("#TermsOfPayment", this.termsOfPayment);
                                    r.setText(text,0);
                                }
                                
                            }else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String dateOnly = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        XWPFTable orderTable = invoiceDocument.createTable(this.invoiceOrder.getOrder().size()+1,8);
        XWPFTableRow nameRow = orderTable.getRow(0);
        nameRow.getCell(0).setText("Product Code");
        nameRow.getCell(1).setText("Product Description");
        nameRow.getCell(2).setText("Price");
        nameRow.getCell(3).setText("Items per Box");
        nameRow.getCell(4).setText("Discount");
        nameRow.getCell(5).setText("Discounted Price");
        nameRow.getCell(6).setText("Quantity");
        nameRow.getCell(7).setText("Amount in USD");
        int row=1;
        for (Product p : this.invoiceOrder.getOrder()) {
            XWPFTableRow productRow = orderTable.getRow(row);
            productRow.getCell(0).setText(p.getProductCode());
            productRow.getCell(1).setText(p.getProductDescription());
            productRow.getCell(2).setText("USD "+p.getProductPriceInUSD());
            productRow.getCell(3).setText(String.valueOf(p.getProductItemsPerBox()));
            productRow.getCell(4).setText(p.getProductDiscount()+"%");
            productRow.getCell(5).setText(String.valueOf(p.getProductDiscountedPrice()));
            productRow.getCell(6).setText(String.valueOf(p.getProductQuantity()));
            productRow.getCell(7).setText("USD "+p.getProductNetValue());
            row++;
        }
        fo = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Desktop/"+this.invoiceClient.getClientName()+"_"+dateOnly+".docx"));
        invoiceDocument.write(fo);
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
        invoiceDocument.close();
        
        return 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```

For example, let's suppose that I change the string "#ClientName" with the string "John". The second reading of the input file will read "John" instead of "#ClientName". When I check the input file I don't see the string "John" anywhere. Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

Comment: What happens with `XWPFDocument invoiceDocument = new XWPFDocument(getClass().getResource("/com/euthimiadis/resources/Proforma_Invoice.docx"));`?

Comment: @g00se this command opens the Word document that is located in the resources of the project and in which I will do the replacements and additions to produce the output file in my Desktop.

Comment: You misunderstand: I know what it does. I'm suggesting you try this instead of your code.

Comment: @g00se Problem solved. Instead of OPCPackage that I used initially, I used FileInputStream and it worked.

Comment: My code has even less (read *zero*) chance of your original being altered, forcing read-only input ;)

Comment: Sorry - noticed a typo - should have been `getResourceAsStream`